# Drawing arrows to nodes in trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

I try to draw rhe following three figures. The left is just a sequence of symbols NP V NP AP, the middle one is a unary branching tree and the right one is a binary brancing tree. I want to place a V below the respective items and connect the V with an arrow to the V in the leftmost figure to the lower V in the middle figure and to the lower right V in the right figure. I guess there is a straightforward way (or several ways) to do this.

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every roof node/.append style={inner sep=0.1pt,text height=2ex,text depth=0.3ex}}

\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}

\newcommand{\trace}{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\_}\rule{0cm}{0.7em}}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(construction.base)]
\draw (0,0) node {V} -- (0,1) node (construction) {NP V NP AP};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(V.base)]
\Tree[.\node (V) {V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP }}; \node (v-in) {V \sliste{ NP }}; ]
\node (v-lex) {V};
\draw (v-lex) (v-in);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(V.base)]
\Tree[.\node (V) {V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP }};
        [.{V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP, [1] }} \trace{} ]
        \node (v-in) {[1] V \sliste{ NP }}; ]
\node (v-lex) {V};
\draw (v-lex) (v-in);
\end{tikzpicture}


\hfill\mbox{}
\caption{\label{phrasal-lexical-empty}Phrasal analysis, lexical analysis and analysis with an empty head}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to clarify your objective. You want a V below each figure (so a total of 3 V's) and connected them via an arrow line.

Comment: Yes, correct!  (did you know that comments must be at least 15 characters in length?) Some people need a lot of words to say yes.

Comment: Ya, someone commented on this weird situation you are facing now.

Answer (score 3):

**New Update:**

If 3 independent `tikzpicture` environment are preferred, the following code achieves that.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every roof node/.append style={inner sep=0.1pt,text height=2ex,text depth=0.3ex}}

\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}

\newcommand{\trace}{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\_}\rule{0cm}{0.7em}}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{line/.style={<->,>=stealth}}  % new style for conneting lines
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering

\raisebox{1.5cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}%[yshift=5cm]
\Tree[.\node (construction) {\phantom{$\langle$}NP V NP AP\phantom{$\rangle$}}; ]
\node[below =0.5cm of construction,xshift=-2ex] (left) {V};
\draw[line] (left.north)  to ([xshift=-2ex]construction.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[xshift=3cm]
\Tree[.\node (V)    {V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP }}; 
          \node (v-in) {V \sliste{ NP }}; ]
\node[below = 2cm of V] (middle) {V};
\draw [line] (middle.north) to ([xshift=-3ex]v-in.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[xshift=8cm]
\Tree[.\node (V) {V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP }};
        [.{V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP, [1] }} ]
        \node (v-in) {[1] V \sliste{ NP }}; ]
\node [below=2cm of V](right) {V};
\draw [line]  (right.north) to ([xshift=-3ex]v-in.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\label{phrasal-lexical-empty}Phrasal analysis, lexical analysis and analysis with an empty head}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

According to the OP's comments below, the connection is different from the first suggestion. Since very designated V has its internal label `left, middle, right`, this update uses them via the following command to connect their upper level v's

```
\draw [name1.north] to ([yshift=-<dim>]name2.south);
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article} 
%\usepackage[papersize={20cm,6cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every roof node/.append style={inner sep=0.1pt,text height=2ex,text depth=0.3ex}}

\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}

\newcommand{\trace}{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\_}\rule{0cm}{0.7em}}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{line/.style={<->,>=stealth}}  % or >=latex' :new style for connecting lines
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\Tree[.\node (construction) {\phantom{$\langle$}NP V NP AP\phantom{$\rangle$}}; ]
\node[below =2cm of construction] (left) {V};
\draw[line] (left.north)  to ([xshift=-2ex]construction.south);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\Tree[.\node (V)    {V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP }}; 
          \node (v-in) {V \sliste{ NP }}; ]
\node[below = 2cm of V] (middle) {V};
\draw [line] (middle.north) to ([xshift=-3ex]v-in.south);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\Tree[.\node (V) {V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP }};
        [.{V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP, [1] }} ]
        \node (v-in) {[1] V \sliste{ NP }}; ]
\node [below=2cm of V](right) {V};
\draw [line]  (right.north) to ([xshift=-3ex]v-in.south);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill\mbox{}
\caption{\label{phrasal-lexical-empty}Phrasal analysis, lexical analysis and analysis with an empty head}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is an attempt where `scope` environment is used to place the three figures with `xshift=xx<dim>` in the `scope` options. Furthermore, the location of V below each figure is determined via `positioning` library from tikz.
[image]

```
   Code

        \documentclass{article} 
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
        \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
        \tikzset{every roof node/.append style={inner sep=0.1pt,text height=2ex,text depth=0.3ex}}

        \newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
        \mbox{%
        $\left\langle\mbox{\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
        }

        \newcommand{\trace}{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\_}\rule{0cm}{0.7em}}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{document}


        \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
        \Tree[.\node (construction) {\phantom{$\langle$}NP V NP AP\phantom{$\rangle$}}; ]
        \node[below =2cm of construction] (left) {V};
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
        \Tree[.\node (V)    {V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP }}; 
                  \node (v-in) {V \sliste{ NP }}; ]
        \node[below = 2cm of V] (middle) {V};
        \draw [<->] (left) to (middle);
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
        \Tree[.\node (V) {V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP }};
                [.{V \sliste{ NP, NP, AP, [1] }} ]
                \node (v-in) {[1] V \sliste{ NP }}; ]
        \node [below=2cm of V](right) {V};
        \draw [<->]  (middle) to (right);
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \hfill\mbox{}
        \caption{\label{phrasal-lexical-empty}Phrasal analysis, lexical analysis and analysis with an empty head}
        \end{center}
        \end{figure}

        \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the Vs in the bottom line should not be connected to each other but to special Vs in the representations above them. The leftmost to the only verb that is there, the middle one to the lowest verb and the right-most V to the right V in the tree. But the `\node[below ]` and the `xshift` hint was already very helpful!

Comment: Ha, that is why I ask before posting mine. Well, every v has an internal label called `left, middle and right`. You can use `\draw [<->](name1) to (name2)` to draw a line with arrow

Comment: @StefanMüller -- Would these changes within each scope (1) `\draw[<->] (left)  to (construction);` (2) `\draw [<->] (middle) -- (v-in);` (3) `\draw [<->]  (right) to (v-in);` be what you need?

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get the left-most V right below the V it points to? The middle and right ones are OK. I will connect to the complete node (v-in) without shifting. The scope and shift solution seems to be problematic if the font size changes because of the absolute positioning. I would stick to the three separate tikzpictures. In fact these are three pictures logically. They are compared in this figure. Does it make sense to have separate tikzpictures?

Comment: Yes, replace the second line in the first scope with `\node[below =0.5cm of construction,xshift=-2ex] (left) {V};`. This will put the v at the place you wish. As to the independent `tikzpicture` like the orignal OP showed, the last one may shift down, and therefore can not be aligned in one line for those 3 tikzpictures. You could put the fontsize into the `tikzpicture` [options] so that the desired fontsize can apply all 3 scopes.

Comment: @Stefan, please see my update for the 3 separate `tikzpicture`s coding. (the system may think we are chatting, if we continue...)